# Is there an elegant way to simultaneously unpack and index key word arguments in python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, indexing, keyword-argument

I have a method which takes some basic arguments (`arg_1` & `arg_2`) as well as some lists of `n` elements, and then uses these arguments in a nested method call, once for each list element like so:

```
def method_one(self, a=arg_1, b=arg_2, list_1, list_2):
    
    for i in range(n):
        method_two(a=arg_1, b=arg_2, c=list_1[i], d=list_2[i])
```

`method_two` is unique to each class, but `method_one` exists in all of the child classes, each of which takes the same basic arguments (`arg_1` & `arg_2`) and a varying number of list arguments (always length `n`).

Is there a way I can use `kwargs` to write a single `method_one` in the parent class which works for all children? Something like:

```
def method_one(self, a=arg_1, b=arg_2, **kwargs):
    
    for i in range(n):
        method_two(a=arg_1, b=arg_2, **kwargs[i])
```

in such a way that `**kwargs[i]` unpacks the key, and ith element of the associated value for all lists arguments in `kwargs`.

Comment: Well, `**kwargs` is inappropriate unless your method is actually being called with keyword parameters - but call it `*args`, and you can use `*[arg[i] for arg in args]`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity: `method_two` does take keyword arguments> I will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you could pass a dictionary comprehension to the `**` unpacking in `method_two`:

```
def method_one(self, arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    for i in range(n):
        method_two(
            arg_1, arg_2,
            **{name: value[i] for name, value in kwargs.items()}
        )
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I was after. I will be back to green-tick once I have implemented it and tested. Thanks.